# How to make New pandas Dataframe from Dask Dataframe without Column shuffling?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask

I'm trying to make a new Dataframe from my Dask Dataframe by using few of the Columns present already. The issue
i'm having is that when I'm making the new Dataframe my Columns values are getting interchanged!

[image: Dask Dataframe]

Now when I'm making a new Dataframe by doing

`new_frame1 = month[['pickup_longitude','pickup_latitude']].compute()`

[image: New Dataframe]

The values in both the columns are getting interchanged for some reason? Is there something I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: I think it would help to know what versions of dask, pandas, and python, etc in which this behavior was encountered, as well as providing a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hi Brian. I think the issue is there in the dask itself. I solved it using firstly computing a blank dask dataframe from the orginal one and then selecting the columns later